# Summing a column and displaying percentage in a number chart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to sum the column `elecVotes` and then divide it by the `elecVote` of a state that has been clicked on so that I can show the percentage of the electoral vote that state is worth and display it in a `dc.numberDisplay`.

This is my data structure:

**//updated**

ElecVotes.csv:

`state,elecVotes,
Alabama,9
Alaska,3
Arkansas,6
Arizona,11
Florida,29
Georgia,16
Iowa,6
Idaho,4
Indiana,11
Kansas,6
Kentucky,8`

data.csv:

`state,party,votes,winner,elecVote
Alabama,Democratic,725704,1,9
Alabama,Republican,1314431,1,9
Alabama,Libertarian,44211,1,9
Alabama,Green,20276,1,9
Alabama,Other,0,1,9
Alabama,Constitution Party,9341,1,9
Alaska,Democratic,116454,1,3
Alaska,Republican,163387,1,3
Alaska,Libertarian,18725,1,3
Alaska,Green,5735,1,3
Alaska,Constitution Party,3866,1,3
Alaska,Other,10441,1,3`

Code:

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {    
    d3.json("us.json", function (json){

        data.forEach(function(r) {
        r.votes = +r.votes;
        r.elecVote = +r.elecVote;
        });       

        var elecVotes = d3.csv.parse("elecVotes")
        var elecVotesMap = d3.map()

        elecVotes.forEach(function(r){
            elecVotesMap.set(r.state, +r.elecVotes)
        });

    // set up crossfilter on the data.
        var ndx = crossfilter(data);

    // set up the dimensions
        var stateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; });
        var stateDim2 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; });
        var stateDim3 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; });
        var partyDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.party; });
        var winnerDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.winner; });
        var elecVotesDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.elecVote;});

        var stateDim4 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; }),
        group = stateDim4.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.elecVote 
        }),
        count = group.top(51);
        count[0].key;
        count[0].value;

    // set up the groups/values
        var state = stateDim.group();
        var party = partyDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.votes;});
        var party2 = partyDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.votes;});
        var winner = stateDim2.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.winner; });
        var elecVotes = stateDim3.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.elecVote; });
        var group = stateDim4.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.votes; } )

    // the 4 different charts - options are set below for each one.
        var pie = dc.pieChart('#chart-pie');
        var usmap = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#usmap");
        var selectMenu = dc.selectMenu('#select-container');
        var percentElec = dc.numberDisplay("#percentage-elec-vote");

        var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Democratic","Republican","Libertarian","Green","Constitution Party","Other"])  //set colour based on party
        .range(["#4682B4","#B22222","#DAA520","#228B22","#80f2ee","#D3D3D3"]);

        var stateColor = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["1","2",""]).range(["#B22222","#4682B4","#B2B7B2"]);    //set colour based on which party won

        selectMenu
        .dimension(stateDim3)
        .group(state)
        .onClick = function() {};

        selectMenu.title(function (d){
            return d.key;
        })

    //create pie from to show popular vote for each state
        pie
        .width(300)
        .height(180)
        .radius(80)
        .dimension(stateDim2)
        .group(party)
        .legend(dc.legend())
        .colors(colorScale)
        .innerRadius(10)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .filter = function() {};

    //number chart to show percentage of electoral vote for each state
        percentElec
        .group(group)
        .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))          
        .valueAccessor(function(d){ return elecVotesMap.get(d.key); })

    //display US map                    
        usmap
        .width(900)
        .height(500)
        .dimension(stateDim)
        .group(winner)
        .colors(stateColor)
        .overlayGeoJson(json.features, "name", function (d) { return d.properties.name; })        

    // at the end this needs to be called to actually go through and generate all the graphs on the page.
    dc.renderAll();

    }); 
    });            

};
```

Comment: `dimension.groupAll()` doesn't have a `reduceSum` method as far as I remember, just a `reduce` method. You have to define custom reducers if you are using groupAll. Since electoral votes are pretty constant, why not maintain an object that maps state to electoral vote and do the lookup in the value access or `dc.numberDisplay`?

Comment: I was writing an answer with `reduceSum` (which does exist afaict) but I agree the map is simpler. It would be tricky to use `reduceSum` with the data denormalized.

Comment: @ethan So are you suggesting I either create a new csv file or an array to store the electoral vote data?

Comment: @MarkHarrison You would probably want to load it from a CSV, but you'll be looking up electoral votes by state, so the right data structure for that would be a Map (or an old-school Object with property lookup).

Comment: @Gordon You're right - `dimension.groupAll().reduceSum` and `dimension.groupAll().reduceCount` both exist and appear to do what would be expected. They aren't in the API docs. Maybe I should fix that :-/

Comment: @Ethan sorry this is causing me some confusion, is this done with Group (Map-Reduce) in crossfilter?

Comment: No, you wouldn't use Crossfilter at all for the electoral votes. Just look them up in the visualization (the dc.js value accessor). If you can put together a simple working example, one of us can update it to provide you guidance.

Comment: @Ethan thanks, I've updated it with what I'm currently trying to do

Comment: @ethan Should I be using JavaScript Array map() to map the data? And then for the numberdisplay I won't need to include a group as all the data will come from the valueAccesor?

Comment: @MarkHarrison I meant to use a Javascript object to do a lookup. In ES6, you would use the Map object type. I don't understand very well what you are trying to do in the updated example because I can't tell what the contents of data.csv and elecVotes.csv look like. Please update the example to include inline example data and an explanation of how the output differs from what you want/expect.

Comment: @EthanJewett To be honest i'm not sure how to map the data. I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two csv files to map the data. With my initial implementation the electoral votes were being summed from every single row, and I also wasn't sure where to divide the sum so that I can get a percentage value.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the file examples you added to the question. That clarifies for me. I will see if I can get you the shape of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to expand on the comments above a bit, here is a fiddle that pretty much shows how I would approach this: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/u9dq33v2/1/

This just loads the data from inline in the page.

```
var elecVotes = d3.csv.parse(document.getElementById("ElecVotes.csv").innerHTML)
var data = d3.csv.parse(document.getElementById("data.csv").innerHTML)
```

Set up your charts. In this example I am using a rowChart as well as the numberDisplay so that you can see how you need to approach dimension/group design for filtering.

```
var percentElec = dc.numberDisplay("#percentage-elec-vote");
var states = dc.rowChart("#state-votes")
```

Set up the Map that you're going to do the lookup of your electoral votes based on the state.

```
var elecVotesMap = d3.map()

elecVotes.forEach(function(r){
  elecVotesMap.set(r.state, +r.elecVotes)
});
```

Set up your Crossfilter and dimension. Note that we are setting up 2 sets of identical dimensions and groups. Groups do not respect filters on their own dimension, so if you use the same dimension (or groups based on the same dimension) in both charts, it *will not filter*.

```
var cf = crossfilter(data)
var dim1 = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; })
var grp1 = dim1.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.votes })

var dim2 = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; })
var grp2 = dim2.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.votes })
```

Set up the state votes rowChart. You can click on this to restrict to just Alabama or Alaska.

```
states
  .dimension(dim1)
  .group(grp1)
```

Set up the numberDisplay. Note that the numberDisplay will display whatever `grp2.top(1)` returns. So if you select more than one state in the rowChart, it will display the state with the most votes (or whatever you have set your `grp2.order()` as). If you want to total everything up, wrap your group with an object with a `top` method that will return what you want to show, and pass the wrapper to the numberDisplay.

In `numberDisplay.valueAccessor`, you have access to both the key and the value of the group. Use the key (the name of the state) to look up the electoral votes for that state. That's what will display.

```
percentElec
  .group(grp2)
  .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))          
  .valueAccessor(function(d){ return elecVotesMap.get(d.key); })

dc.renderAll()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, just wondering if you could look at my code again, sorry for the late reply. I think I've entered the code correctly (i've updated my code above), but the number display is displaying NaN.

Comment: Start going through it in the browser console with `console.log` or with the debugger. The first problem I see is with `var elecVotes = d3.csv.parse("elecVotes")`, which is asking d3 to parse the string "elecVotes" as CSV. Here's an overview of how to use the console in Chrome, which gets into basic debugging using `console.log`: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Thanks got it working. Is this the top method you're describing? https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_top

Comment: Cool :-) And yes, that's the method, though the maintained version of Crossfilter is here: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter and the docs are here: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference  Cheers!

Comment: Again thanks, and to turn the summed values into a percentage could I just divide the value in the .valueAccessor?

Comment: Yes, that's usually the best approach. Good luck!

Comment: I don't quite understand the `top` method, doesn't it just return an array sorted by the top values? Wouldn't I need to do a group reduce to sum the values?

Comment: `group.top` returns an array of top groups as defined by `group.order` under the current set of filters (excluding the filter on the group's own dimension if there is one). These are aggregated values. `dimension.top` returns an array of records sorted by the ordering of the dimension accessor (observing *all* filters including this dimension's filter).

Comment: BTW, there is a Gitter chat linked from the crossfilter/crossfilter readme. I'd recommend moving this sort of running discussion over there :-)