# How to wrap a group with a top method

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a map display and would like to total all electoral votes of the states that have been selected and display it in a number display. I was given the advice in a previous thread to wrap my group with an object with a top method. I'm not sure how to do this, so far I have:

```
var stateDim4 = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.state; }),
        group = stateDim4.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.elecVote }),
        count = group.top(51);
    count[0].key;
    count[0].value;
```

Please could someone help me on how to do this?
Previous Thread: [Summing a column and displaying percentage in a number chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162353/summing-a-column-and-displaying-percentage-in-a-number-chart/43285664?noredirect=1#comment74023973_43285664)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your previous example, here is a fake group with a `top` method that sums up all the electoral votes for the selected states.

```
var fakeGroup = {
    top: function() {
    return [
        grp2.top(Infinity).reduce(function(a,b) {
        if(b.value > 0) {
          a.value += elecVotesMap.get(b.key)
        }
        return a
      }, {
        key: "",
        value: 0
      })
    ]
  }
}


percentElec
  .group(fakeGroup)
  .formatNumber(d3.format("d"))
```

Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/u9dq33v2/2/

There are a bunch of other fake group examples in the [dc.js FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups), but I don't think any of them do exactly what you want here.

Comment: Thanks, this is returning the error group.all is not a function in the number-display.js

Comment: Are you running an older version of dc.js? This is running on the 2.1 dev branch, which may use `top` instead of `all`. Try replacing `top` with `all` in the example, maybe?

Comment: If you're using dc.js 2.0.* or earlier, you'll probably need [both `.top()` and `.all()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#-but-i-need-top). If you're running 2.1.* you only need `.all()` (and might [need to set `chart.ordering`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#ordering__anchor)).

Comment: I just changed to the version you were using in the example and it works. Thank you :)